# Run c++ mex s-function in rapid accelerator mode

Tags: c++, simulink, mex, accelerator

I need to implement c++ code into my simulink model and it has to run in `Rapid Accelerator Mode`. Therefore, I used the S-function builder to generate a blank sfunction (`Sim.c`), a sfunction wrapper (`Sim_wrapper.c`) and a tlc-file (`Sim.tlc`) (required for code generation).

Once I tried to use my c++ libs, errors occured. So I renamed the .c-files into .cpp-files an changed the line `%implements  Sim "C"` to `%implements  Sim "C++"`. But I got the error Warning: `Rapid accelerator only supports C code.`

Is there any way to get c++-code running in rapid accelerator mode?